# Classic ASP - Get value of textboxes starting with specific name

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

**Hi,**

I'm creating dynamic input textboxes starting with name: `loan0` and also name: `balance0`
I would like to have classic asp put the values into two arrays

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="John">
<input type="text" name="phone" value="1234567">

<input type="text" name="loan0" value="bla">
<input type="text" name="loan1" value="blabla">
<input type="text" name="balance0" value="test1">
<input type="text" name="balance1" value="test2">
...........and so on...............
```

**Classic ASP:**

```
loan_array = bla,blabla ... and so on..
balance_array = test1,test2 ... and so on...
```

**What I tried:**

```
dim loan_array
loan_array = ""
For Each item In Request.Form
    loan_array = loan_array & Request.Form(item) & ","
Next
 Response.write loan_array
end if
```

**PROBLEM:** The result I get back is all of the values in all of the input textboxes, but I only want those that start with the name balance followed by a number (starting with 0) and loan followed by a number (starting with 0)

THANKS SO MUCH FOR ANY HELP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do this when ASP can do it for you?

HTML:

```html
<input type="text" name="name" value="John">
<input type="text" name="phone" value="1234567">

<input type="text" name="loan" value="bla">
<input type="text" name="loan" value="blabla">
<input type="text" name="balance" value="test1">
<input type="text" name="balance" value="test2">
<!-- ...........and so on............... -->
```

Classic ASP:

```vb
Response.Write Request.Form("loan")
```

Output:

```
bla, blabla
```

ASP will even build the delimited string based on the order of the form elements with the same name occur.

---

#### Update:

Based on [feedback about handling commas inside the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085106/classic-asp-get-value-of-textboxes-starting-with-specific-name/39086421?noredirect=1#comment65559552_39086421), I've done a bit of testing myself and the issue is due to how `Request.Form("loan")` automatically decodes and collates the entries together but there is a simple way around this and that is to iterate through the instances of `Request.Form("loan")` rather then just calling `Request.Form("loan")` and having them automatically collated together.

HTML:

```html
<input type="text" name="loan" value="bla">
<input type="text" name="loan" value="blabla">
<input type="text" name="loan" value="test1,test2">
<input type="text" name="loan" value="test3">
<!-- ...........and so on............... -->
```

Classic ASP:

```vb
Dim item
For Each item In Request.Form("loan")
  Response.Write item & "<br />"
Next
```

Output:

```
bla
blabla
test1,test2
test3
```

Comment: True, I just wanted to see if there was a way to do it.

Comment: @compcobalt it absolutely is doable my point was simply why re-invent the wheel. Is there a specific use case?

Comment: your 100% right, why reinvent the wheel.. :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, but how do I deal with an input textbox that has a comma in the value. Is there a way to cover it to "bla","blabla" and then seperate it by "," or something like that ? because like this if the user enters a comma it will think its another array but its actually not, Thanks

Comment: @compcobalt I would have to test it but if a comma is entered in the `input` and the `form` is submitted doesn't the posted value get encoded so comma would be `%2C`?

Comment: can you please test it, when I do it shows up as another comma. Thanks for your continued help.

Comment: I just tested it by saving it to a ms sql field (varchar) but it doesn't know %2C it shows a comma.. Is there anything I can do to correct this ?

Comment: @compcobalt I've updated my answer, should support commas fine.

Comment: yup This is great... Thanks a 1,000,000 :)

Answer (score 1):

The way you *should* do it is what Lankymart wrote, i.e. using the same name for all the related fields, and letting ASP do the concatenating-to-string for you. (And then if you want it as an array, you can just do a `Split()` on the commas.) However, if you really want to do it yourself, you can concatenate field names in `Request.Form`:

```
N = Request.Form("N") '- number of fields per type
redim loan_array(N) : redim balance_array(N)
For i = 0 to N
    loan_array(i) = Request.Form("loan" & i)
    '- might as well take advantage of this one-at-a-time approach:
    If Not IsNumeric(loan_array(i)) Then 
        loan_array(i) = 0
    Else
        loan_array(i) = CLng(loan_array(i))
    End If
    balance_array(i) = Request.Form("balance" & i)
    '- etc.
Next
'- one reason for doing it this way might be that your data has commas in it:
Const delimiter = ";"
loan_list = Join(loan_array,delimiter)
balance_list = Join(balance_array,delimiter)
```

This counts on there being a known number of fields of each type, but I can't imagine a scenario where you don't know that - if nowhere else, right after generating/writing out your form:

```
<input type="text" name="loan0" value="<%=loan_array(0)%>">
<input type="text" name="loan1" value="<%=loan_array(1)%>">
<input type="text" name="loan2" value="<%=loan_array(2)%>">
...
<input type="hidden" name="N" value="2">
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for your answer. Yes, commas will be allowed to be entered into the textbox and this will cause a problem. I tried your code but I don't understand what I do with N = Request.Form("N") .... Do I need to know the total textboxes or ??, I don't understand what that is for, I tried running the code but it doesnt work for me.

Comment: I just noticed it works but only with numbers, if I enter letters in there it will show a zero. I would love to use your approach because it would allow commas to be entered into the textbox but I need to be able to enter letters into the textbox also.

Comment: as for the count (N)... Is there a way I can count the number of fields with almost the same name ? like maybe by searching for the input name that start with the name loan ? I want to do it on the asp side vs javascript if possible. thx

Comment: @compcobalt: my sample code is testing for `IsNumeric`, just as an example of the sort of thing you can do. Obviously, if your inputs aren't supposed to be numeric, then you should change or remove that. As far as knowing the number of fields, how is the form being generated? I really can't imagine a scenario where you can write a certain number of fields to the form, but can't also write a hidden field with that same number in it.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps this will help.

```
dim loan_array, myCounter
loan_array = ""
myCounter = 0
For Each item In Request.Form
loan_array = loan_array & Request.Form(item) & myCounter & ", "
myCounter = myCounter+1
Next
Response.write loan_array
```

Comment: it still shows all of the items. I just need the values of the ones that have the input textbox name of loan0 and loan1 and so on... same with balance0